# Sending mail to Gmail from wordpress

Tags: wordpress, email, phpmailer

I am using Wordpress 4.0.0 for a blogging website.

During registration of a new user it send an activation link via mail. Yahoo gets mail correctly, **but Gmail doesn't**.

I've tried `mail-smtp` plugin, but it doesn't work.

Here is a code I use now:

```
function new_mail_from($old) {
    return 'name@mydomain.com';
}

function new_mail_from_name($old) {
   return 'name';
}

add_filter('wp_mail_from', 'new_mail_from');
add_filter('wp_mail_from_name', 'new_mail_from_name');
```

Why this problem occurs and how it can be solved?

Comment: have you check your mail in spam/junk in gmail??

Comment: yz, it's not in spam/junk

Comment: follow this article to check your domain is not blacklisted by google: http://wpseer.com/how-to-check-if-a-domain-is-blacklisted-by-google/
http://www.websitepulse.com/help/testtools.dbl-test.html

Comment: You need to post your code. Make sure you are not trying to use the user's email address as the from address. That will usually cause SPF failures.

Comment: Yes, the from address needs to be different to the recipient for it to show up in Gmail; try sending to a different Google account.

Comment: its not same from and send address, its already works in yahoo mails. Only not work in gmail

Comment: @lffi   Result of checking:
Lookup server Open Proxy Spam Other Details
dnsrbl.net NO NO NO v=spf1 -all
cbl.abuseat.org NO NO NO -
proxies.blackholes.easynet.net NO NO NO -
sbl-xbl.spamhaus.org NO NO NO -
psbl.surriel.com NO NO NO -
dnsbl.sorbs.net No response 

  Is this any problem?

Comment: Does your domain have a [SPF record](https://support.google.com/a/answer/33786?hl=en) configured? I often found that's the problem with Gmail as recipient.

Comment: The code you have provided tells us nothing, so all you will receive is guesses. Check your local mail server logs.

Answer (score 0):

This might be transient due to the Google certificate problem for smtp.googel.com? See for example here: http://www.pcworld.com/article/2906216/expired-google-certificate-temporarily-disrupts-gmail-service.html

Have any concrete error in the logs so we can see where the problem exists?

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @SonerGönül I did not intend to give a technical answer to the question since the OP doesn't give any information about the setup or code. I do mention all the relevant parts in the answer and the link to the article is purely for further reading. What was it you would like to see included in the answer? Perhaps you could edit it and add it instead?